# Django: given a user object, how do I get a corresponding UserProfile object?

Tags: python, django, authentication

Have a `UserProfile` object that successfully extends the django default `user` class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and have updated the `settings.py` file accordingly:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'authorization.UserProfile'
```

Everything works fine, just wondering: how do I get to objects associated with `UserProfile` for a given context within a view?

Assume that I can just get `context.user` if the user is logged in, but then how do I grab the corresponding `UserProfile` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view:

```
 request.user.get_profile().field_name
```

In template:

```
 {{user.userprofile.field_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like -

```
context.user.userprofile
```

[Detail here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).